# redirect domain from 1&1 to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cname, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect the domain that I bought from 1&1 to GAE.

Right now, my domain is redirecting to my appengine app, but the problem is that if I write in the browser's URL the following: www.mydomain.com, it is redirected to http://myappid.appspot.com (instead of redirect to http://myappid.appspot.com but showing on the URL the same domain --> www.mydomain.com).

Does anyone know how can I configure it on 1&1?

This is my 1&1 configuration:

```
Domain name --> mydomain.com (MX)
Type --> Domain
Destination --> Redirection(http://myappid.appspot.com)
Register --> Public
Status --> Activated
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a frame redirect.

(1) Set up a subdomain called "www", and have your naked domain (mydomain.com) redirect to www.mydomain.com as an http redirect.

(2) Sign up for "Google Apps for Business" using "mydomain.com" as your domain.

(3) In the Google Apps dashboard, find "App Engine Apps", and add your app-id.

(4) Click on your app-id and From there you can add additional web addresses for your app.  Add "www.mydomain.com" here.

(5) In 1&1 you'll have to update your www.mydomain.com DNS settings as CNAME, with alias "ghs.googlehosted.com"

With all that done, mydomain.com will http redirect to www.mydomain.com, which in turn will alias to ghs.googlehosted.com, which in turn will pull up your app.

You can then cleanly use your domain URIs, ex: "mydomain.com/getPineappleStatus?id=12"

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation explains how to set up a domain to use Google app engine. See the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: Please... If I wrote it here is because I didn't see anything in the official documentation. If you read correctly the official documentation, it doesn't shows anything about the question I wrote. Please, don't answer without read corretly the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (using a frame redirection)

[Link](http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_admin/domain_dest/3.html)